# Firebase -How to check if a phone number exists inside phone auth before creating a new user

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Using email when logging in a new user or creating a new user there are 2 different method signatures. When creating a new user if the email already exists an error will be returned or logging a user in if the email doesn't exist an error will be returned:

```
// create account
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: { (authDataResult, error)

    if let error = error {

       // if this email address already exists an error will be returned
       return
    }
})

// login 
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!, completion: { (authDataResult, error) in

    if let error = error {

       // if this email address isn't inside the system then an error will be returned
       return
    }
})
```

But when using a user's phone number to log them is or create a new account I have to use the same method signature for both situations.

```
func loginExistingUserOrCreateNewOne(phoneNumber: String, verificationCode: String) {

    PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in

        if let error = error { return }

        guard let verificationId = verificationID else { return }

        let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationId, verificationCode: verificationCode)

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (authDataResult, error) in

            guard let authUser = authDataResult else { return }

            let checkUsersRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(authUser.user.uid)
            checkExistingUsersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                if !snapshot.exists() {
                    // this is a new user, now add them to the users ref

                    let newUserDict = ["signupDate": Date().timeIntervalSince1970]
                    checkUsersRef.updateChildValues(newUserDict, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in

                        if let error = error {

                            // because there is an error this ref was never updated so now I have to sign this user out and they have to start over agin
                            do {
                                try Auth.auth().signOut()

                            } catch let err as NSError {

                                // alert user there is a major problem
                            }
                            return
                        }

                        // if no error let them go to HomeVC
                    })

                    return
                }

                // this is a previous user fetch dict data and let them proceed to HomeVC
                guard let previousUserDict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

                // get newUserDict values and let them go to HomeVC
            })
        })
    }
}
```

If a user already has an account I need to fetch some data from the users ref and then I let them proceed to HomeVC. If the user has never signed up before then I have to add them to the users ref and then let them proceed. It's a 2 step process.

The problem is these extra steps seems unnecessary. For example using email sign or login an error is returned so there is no need to create and check inside another ref to see if that email already exists.

**Outside of using the process in my above code is there any other way that I can determine if a phone number exists before creating a new account or if it doesn't exist when logging in?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use the admin sdk to [lookup a user by phone number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data):

```
admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // User exists.
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    if (error.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
      // User not found.
    }
  });
```

You can use a Cloud Function to host an HTTP endpoint. Looking up a user by phone number is only possible via authenticated APIs running server side (using the Firebase Admin SDKs).

Comment: Thanks. My XCode has been on the fritz for several hrs. Once I get it working I’ll try it and get back you.

Comment: Do you have the Swift version of the code? I looked at the link and I didn’t see it.

Comment: This is using the Admin SDK. It is running server side. They don't have a client API for this.

Comment: @bjeil my project doesn't use the Admin SDK. I have a little experience with Node.js, this looks like it and like it would belong in an app.js file: const admin = require("firebase-admin"); admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber(...). I don't think it's possible to add the above code to an Xcode Swift file (the vc with the code from my question).

Comment: You have to run this server side. You can use a Cloud Function to host the http endpoint. This is the only possible way to lookup a user by phone number.

Comment: Can add your comment to your answer? Other people need to see it and I will accept it. "You can use a Cloud Function to host the http endpoint. This is the only possible way to lookup a user by phone number". Firebase should've made that more clear. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok. I added the clarification.